# Fullscreen app location in Mission Control

Tags: mission-control, fullscreen

Is is possible to make the fullscreen applications be put right next to the desktop you are currently on, rather than to the right of all existing desktops in Mission Control?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, go into System Preferences>Mission Control. Check the box next to "Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use"

Comment: Does that actually do what I want? I thought that just arranged the spaces randomly based on what it thinks you use

Comment: No, it rearranges based on most recent use. You can always disable it if it isn't what you want.

Comment: This is not quite what I'm looking for. I only want to affect the location of new spaces.

Comment: This isn't possible in that configuration then